# Equivalence classes of polynomials under function transformations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, polynomials, equivalence-relations, transformation

Consider the sets of degree $n$ polynomials,
$$P_{n} = \big\{ a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots a_1 x + a_0\ : a_{n} \neq 0 \big\},$$
and the collection of classical function transformations:

- **horizontal dilation**: $p(x) \mapsto p(x/k), \quad \text{where $k\neq 0$} $
- **vertical dilation**: $p(x) \mapsto k p(x), \quad \text{where $k \neq 0$}$
- **horizontal translation**: $p(x) \mapsto p(x-k)$
- **vertical translation**: $p(x) \mapsto p(x) + k$

It's clear that any composition of these transformations will map $P_n$ to itself. Moreover, it seems reasonable that these operations should allow us to define a set of congruence classes on the set $P_n$ defined as follows:

> For $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ in $P_n$, we say that $p(x) \sim q(x)$ if and only if there is a set of function transformations which transform $p(x)$ into $q(x)$.

Obviously this relationship is reflexive, since $p(x) \sim p(x)$ by the identity transformation; and since each transformation has an inverse transformation, then the symmetric and transitive properties of $\sim$ should hold as well.

This brings me to my actual question:

> What (if anything) can be said about the set of equivalence classes, $P_{n} \,/ \sim$?

Of note, since all parabolas are similar this means, interestingly enough, that $\left|P_{2}\, / \sim\right| = 1$, since the equivalence class $\left[x^2\right]$ contains all quadratics. I'm just not sure how to even approach something like $P_3 \,/ \sim$ or beyond, so any suggestions would be quite welcomed.

Comment: It's unclear to me how $x^2$ is congruent to $x^2+x$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField just complete the square

Comment: @Patch what have you tried to deduce in the "best" case i.e. polynomials with $n$ distinct real roots? Then you can figure out how this generalizes with mixed multiplicities or polynomials that don't fully factor over the reals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the horizontal transformations affects the position of the critical points $\{ x : p'(x) = 0 \}$; horizontal dilation dilates them, and horizontal translation translates them. This means that, for example, if $\deg p = 4$ and $p'$ has all real roots, then generically $p$ has three real critical points $c_1 < c_2 < c_3$ and so all four transformations leave the ratio

$$\frac{c_3 - c_1}{c_2 - c_1}$$

invariant. More generally, if $p$ has $k$ distinct real critical points $c_1 < c_2 < \dots < c_k$ then all four transformations leave invariant the point in projective space with coordinates $(c_k - c_1 : c_{k-1} - c_1 : \dots c_2 - c_1)$ (or, if you prefer, they leave invariant all ratios of the form $\frac{c_i - c_j}{c_k - c_{\ell}}$).

Conversely, if $p$ and $q$ are two polynomials of the same degree and their *complex* critical points (including multiplicity) have the property that it's possible to dilate and translate one set to become the other, then $p \sim q$. But unlike the real critical points, the complex critical points don't come in any preferred order, so it's not immediately clear to me how to translate this criterion into the equality of some more concrete set of invariants. In any case the passage to the (multi)set of critical points has the effect of ignoring the vertical transformations so one is left only to contemplate the effect of the horizontal ones. You can use this to write down a normal form by translating so that the complex critical points add up to $0$, then dilating so that e.g. the largest critical point in absolute value has absolute value $1$ or something like that.

This line of reasoning correctly suggests that the quadratic case is somewhat degenerate, since when $\deg p = 2$ there is only one critical point (the vertex of the parabola) and any two such critical points can be translated to each other.

The cubic case is also somewhat degenerate but less so. When $\deg p = 3$ there are two critical points so if they are distinct and real any two pairs of such critical points can be translated and dilated into each other. This suggests that the cubic case should split into a finite set of cases based on whether the roots of $p'(x)$ are distinct or real, and in fact you can show that any cubic is equivalent to exactly one of the cubics $x^3 + x, x^3, x^3 - x$, corresponding to the critical points being complex, there being a single critical point of multiplicity $2$, or the critical points being distinct and real. (Vertically dilate and translate to set the $x^3$ coefficient to $1$ and the constant coefficient to $0$, horizontally translate to set the $x^2$ coefficient to $0$, then horizontally dilate to normalize the $x$ coefficient.)

You can guess ahead of time that the quadratic and cubic cases are degenerate compared to the others because you have a $4$-parameter family of transformations (formally, a $4$-dimensional Lie group) whereas the polynomials of degree $n$ form an $n+1$-parameter family, so heuristically the transformations can successfully cut down the continuous variations of the polynomials iff $n+1 \le 4$ and this is what we observe.

Comment: Thank you for all of this! I'll be reading through it more carefully over the next day or two, but there is a lot of interesting stuff in there that seems totally in line with what I was looking for. I'll go ahead an accept this as the answer when I'm done with that.

Comment: P.S. If you have the time, I'd love to see some elaboration on the "4 dimensional Lie group" part. I'm not super familiar with the concept of Lie groups, but I have a rough idea of why your example would constitute one; I'd just like to see your thoughts on it as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Patch: there's a $2$-dimensional Lie group consisting of maps of the form $x \mapsto ax + b$ (combinations of dilations and translations) called the affine group (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group) $AGL_1(\mathbb{R})$. Here we have two copies of the affine group acting, one horizontally and one vertically, so the result is a $4$-dimensional Lie group given by their direct product.

Comment: So everything you said in the first few paragraphs makes sense to me, but I'm not sure I know what the "point" of the last statement is. Are you saying $P_4 \,/\sim$ is not finite? Because there is something inherently "continuous" about the problem? Based on your initial comments I would have thought you could enumerate the equivalence classes based on the number/multiplicity of their critical points (I'm also just thinking about the real case for now)

Comment: @Patch: yes, from degree $4$ onward the equivalence classes (generically) vary continuously in families and the first few paragraphs are a proof of this (since those ratios $\frac{c_i - c_j}{c_k - c_{\ell}}$ vary continuously). The equivalence classes do split up into components based on the multiplicity of the critical points and whether they are real or complex but each of these components has positive dimension.

Comment: Everything you've outlined makes a lot of sense now (thanks again!) but I have one last question: It seems perfectly reasonable that if $[p'] \neq [q']$ in $P_{n-1}\,/\sim$ then $[p] \neq [q]$ in $P_{n}\,/\sim$. But how should one **prove** that? It's not coming to me right away...

Comment: @Patch: it's easier to prove the contrapositive: if $p \sim q$ then $p' \sim q'$. This is straightforward, you just look at the effect of performing each of the transformations then differentiating.

Comment: Ah! Of course. Thanks.